# Apache Storm - Nimbus, Supervisors, Workers getting stopped silently

Tags: apache-storm

I am using Apache Storm 0.9.5 version and Java 1.7
I am facing below issue.

There is a sudden death of all STORM processes happens.
I ran the topology for once and observed for 1 or 2 days without sending any data.
After then when I see the processes, they will be not running.

Also I have set the  `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` in Storm.yaml in all the nodes for nimbus, supervisor and workers.

But When I see the GC logs, it is saying

```
PSPermGen       total 27136K, used 26865K [0x0000000760000000, 0x0000000761a80000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 27136K, 99% used [0x0000000760000000,0x0000000761a3c480,0x0000000761a80000)
```

It is just 27MB alloted for PermGen space. Is STORM not taking 512MB of ram?

Please let me know why there is a sudden death seen for all these processes.
Thank you.

Comment: can you post exactly how did you changed the PemSize?

Comment: In storm.yaml configuration file, we can specify as below.
=======================
supervisor.childopts: "-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
worker.childopts: "-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"

=======================

Comment: Did Nimbus, Supervisors, Workers leave error logs? If it does, could you share logs?

Comment: I verified logs as well. But there is no error indication about this issue in the logs. Logs seems to be proper.

Answer (score 1):

Added a monitoring process"supervisord" to monitor the master nimbus and supervisros. This way I made, required processes to be always UP and running.

Since Storm fall under fail-fast design category, a separate monitoring process is required to have 24/7 HA support for nimbus and supervisor processes.

Comment: Did you found any root cause why worker stopped silently?

Comment: Basically Storm follows fail-fast design, so we no need to search for run time errors. Just put monitor process to restart it.